# EmberJS - Access application controller from other controllers

Tags: ember.js

How to access application controller from another controller?

Or

How to access another controller from controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Application Controller:**

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({

   findPersonById: function(id) {
   .....
   ....
   }
});
```

Below is the way to access application controller function inside comments controller.

**Comments Controller**

```
App.CommentsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({

   needs: ["application"],

   getComments: function() {

   var person = this.get("controllers.application").findPersonById(id);
   ....
   ....
   }

});
```